# After add tag form to code not success preview

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm user  this  code  is  success run

```
<body>
        <p class="c1">this  is  test text</p>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Click"/>
</body>
```

and css

```
.c1{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: red;
}

.c2{
    font-size:10px;
    color:blueviolet;
}
```

and  js

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var newClass = 'c2';
        $('p')
                .removeAttr('class')
                .addClass(newClass);
    });
});
```

code  is  success  run

but after add form tag  to code  not success preview

```
 <body>
        <form action="" method="post"> 
            <p class="c1">this  is  test text</p>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Click"/>
        </form>
    </body>
```

[link 1](http://jsfiddle.net/vistacali/2z26t8aL/)

[link 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vistacali/hu9ojduv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `preventDefault()` on the event to prevent the `form` from submitting:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newClass = 'c2';
        $('p')
                .removeAttr('class')
                .addClass(newClass);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hu9ojduv/1/)

Comment: what after add event preventDefault not  work onClick